# Creating winforms base controls

Tags: c#, winforms

We have several winforms applications we want to restyle and make consistent (styling wise).  We want to create some base classes for some of the windows controls such as buttons and toolstrip.  All my base classes intend to do is specify the specific styling we wish to apply.  This works the first time I bring into my form but later on if I wish to update a property it doesn't apply it back to the forms that previously already have pulled it in.  Anyway to get this to work?  Here's an example, lets say I want to create a base class for a toolstrip.  All I want to do is set the backcolor to green (I really want to set more properties but this is to demo my issue).  So I create a class library called BaseControls and create a class called BaseToolStrip and set the backcolor to green in its constructor.

```
public class BaseToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
  public BaseToolStrip()
  {
    BackColor = Color.Green; 
  }
}
```

Now if I create a demo project and add an instance of BaseToolStrip to the form it works.  It creates a green toolstrip.  Later if I decided I want my base toolstrip to have a backcolor of red if I update the constructor in my BaseToolStrip class and set the BackColor = Color.Red and run my solution the color is still green.  It appears that once I've brought that control in it set backcolor = green.  So even though in my base class I set backcolor = red in my form that instantiates it still has backcolor = green.  Any way to override all instances and set backcolor equal to the color specified in my BaseToolStrip class?

Comment: Side note that isn't a base class it's an inherited class as such something like `MyStyledToolStrip` would be better.

Comment: Is this only a problem in the designer or does it happen at runtime too?

Comment: Happens at runtime also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the WinForms designer is saving the current value in `InitializeComponent()` in any designer that uses that control.
That happens after your ctor runs and replaces your value.

You can prevent that by overriding / shadowing the property and adding `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` (you'll need to reopen & resave all designers that use it to remove the property).

Comment: The side effect of this is that no changes to BackColor will ever be saved. Maybe that's desirable for you, but if you wanted to do that, I would also fix the setter so it never changes from your default - since you're overriding it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the default value for the property (as well as setting the actual value in the ctor):

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Green")]
public override Color BackColor {
   get { return base.BackColor; }
   set { base.BackColor = value; }
}
```

I do not have VS available to test right now, but I think that will cause the designer to notice that the current value is the default, and therefore doesn't need to be saved in the Designer.cs.

So if you change the color in both places later, it should update everywhere.

Of course, this will only work for controls that you drag onto a form *after* you add this code, since the others already have the value saved.